# TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_lenght' django

Tags: django

do you know why get this error for below code?

"TypeError: Field.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_lenght'"

thanks,
M

```
    from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

STATUS = ((0, 'Draft'), (1, 'Published'))
# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_post')
    created_on= models.DataTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DataTimeField(auto_now=True)
    conent = models.TextField()
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

attaching log:

```
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\mi\Moj\Development\Blog\mysite\blog\models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Post(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\mi\Moj\Development\Blog\mysite\blog\models.py", line 8, in Post
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=200, unique=True)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mi\Moj\Development\Blog\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1139, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_lenght'
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback. You've misspelled "lenght" in the posted error message but the spelling looks okay in the code.

Comment: Sorry I was editing, uploaded log in main post.thx

Comment: The line in the traceback doesn't match your code. Have you fixed the problem and are running old code?

Comment: sorry, uploaded one more time

Comment: You've misspelled the parameter in the file at `C:\Users\mi\Moj\Development\Blog\mysite\blog\models.py`.

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly is not correct in this file, I included whole  code from this file?

Comment: Right. But look at the error message. It clearly shows a misspelling. So you have 2 versions of the code. I don't know why you see one thing and run another. Is is just a question of hitting the save button? Code in two places? It says line 8 in the error, but it appears to be line 7 in the code. So, two different bits of code.

Comment: thanks  for hint, seems after restarting I got different error which I was able to fix